# Iterator, loop causing seg fault! Why is it looping too much?

Tags: c++, loops, iterator, segmentation-fault

The following code is going through the loop too many times, and I'm baffled as to why. I've looked around and haven't seen a case exactly like this. I'm fairly new to iterators so there may be something simple here. Thank you for the help! And hopefully responses to this help others in the future.

```
std::multimap<std::string,std::vector<Token> >::iterator end = theFacts.returnContents().end();
for (mapITER = theFacts.returnContents().begin() ; mapITER != end; mapITER++) {

  cout << "ANOTHER ITERATION THROUGH FACTS" << endl;
  cout << mapITER->first << endl;
  cout << contents.begin()->first << endl;

  if (mapITER->first == contents.begin()->first) {

    cout << "same scheem type so I keep going!" << endl;

    bool successfull = true;

    cout << "starting to seek match --> size --> " << mapITER->second.size() << endl;

    for (int x = 0; x< mapITER->second.size(); x++) {

      std::cout << "processing! "
                << mapITER->second[x].getTokensValue() << "<<<<<<is equal?>>>>>>"
                << contents.begin()->second[x].getTokensValue() << std::endl;

      if (mapITER->second[x].getTokensValue()
        == contents.begin()->second[x].getTokensValue()) {

        cout << "pushing value" << endl;
        newBaby.push_back(contents.begin()->second[x]);

      } else {

        cout << "failure" << endl;
        successfull = false;
      }
    }

    if (successfull) {

      std::cout << "match successfully found" << std::endl;

      if (returnme.contents.empty()) {

        returnme = Relation(contents.begin()->first, newBaby);
        cout << returnme.toString() << endl;

      } else {

        returnme.relationInsert(contents.begin()->first, newBaby);
        cout << returnme.toString() << endl;
      }

    } else {
      // Anser is NO
    }
  }
}
```

I know I'm not providing the full code, but as you can see form the following output, the size of the map I'm iterating through is 2, so why is it looping a third time!

```
WHERE TO END --> size of maps (number of iterations that shoudl occure2
ANOTHER ITERATION THROUGH FACTS
snap
snap
same scheem type so I keep going!
starting to seek match --> size --> 4
processing! '12345'<<<<<<is equal?>>>>>>'67890'
failure
processing! 'Snoopy'<<<<<<is equal?>>>>>>'Van Pelt'
failure
processing! '12 Apple'<<<<<<is equal?>>>>>>'34 Pear'
failure
processing! '555-1234'<<<<<<is equal?>>>>>>'555-5678'
failure
ANOTHER ITERATION THROUGH FACTS
snap
snap
same scheem type so I keep going!
starting to seek match --> size --> 4
processing! '67890'<<<<<<is equal?>>>>>>'67890'
pushing value
processing! 'Van Pelt'<<<<<<is equal?>>>>>>'Van Pelt'
pushing value
processing! '34 Pear'<<<<<<is equal?>>>>>>'34 Pear'
pushing value
processing! '555-5678'<<<<<<is equal?>>>>>>'555-5678'
pushing value
match successfully found
PRINT RELATION CALLED 
snap('67890','Van Pelt','34 Pear','555-5678')
ANOTHER ITERATION THROUGH FACTS
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

here is what return contents does.

```
std::multimap<std::string,std::vector<Token> > Relation :: returnContents()
{
    return contents;
}
```

where contents is a private variable in the Relation class. Doesn't seem to me it should cause error, unless there is something obvious I don't know.

Comment: It would help if you showed enough code to diagnose the problem, like where is `end` declared and what is its value?

Comment: What is `end` in `mapITER != end`?

Comment: try mapITER != theFacts.end() in your condition. And a pre-incrementation is better with iterator (you don't do a copy of the object)

Comment: Guess: `theFacts.returnContents()` doesn't return a reference.

Comment: I added my instantiation of end. It appears to be seg faulting when it goes through the loop an extra (in this case 3rd) time and tries to pull mapITER->first. I don't understand why it's going through the loop a third time!

Comment: Also, I just tested it with pre increment (++mapITER) in the for argument, and I'm still getting the same behaviour. :(

Comment: @molbdnilo Pretty safe guess.  I'd guess that as well.

Comment: Hmm, why might that be? I just tried printing that object to string before running the for loop and it does indeed exist. I'll post returnContents() right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> here is what return contents does.

There you have your error. The function `returnContents` returns a *copy* of the map. You then call `begin` and `end` on two different copies from it.

Either return a (const) reference:

```
const std::multimap<std::string,std::vector<Token> >& Relation::returnContents() {
    return contents;
}
```

or create a local copy:

```
std::multimap<std::string,std::vector<Token> > tmp = theFacts.returnContents();
for (mapITER = tmp.begin() ; mapITER != tmp.end(); mapITER++) { ...
```

Comment: That was definitely it. Thank you much! If ended up making a copy. Though I would like to knwo, if I were to send a const reference through, and make manipulations on the contents, would those changes be made on the original object? (Is this the same as passing a pointer?)

Comment: If you use a const reference you can not change the contents. You would require a non-const reference/pointer. But I would not make changes to the map while iterating over it.